# android click event handling doesn't work causing the app to stop running

Tags: android

I am trying to create a button from using an image, and add the event handling for that. 
However, I get some errors when adding the highlighted code (please refer to the second image when clicking on this link [Code](http://imgur.com/a/MQwLQ) )

Image 1: the errors
Image 2: the java code
Image 3: xml code

Thank you in advance. 
Let me know if you would like further info

Comment: Please copy and paste the code and error message here.

Answer (score 0):

just do this

first remove line
//int buttonid line

and replace

```
imageButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(buttonid);
```

with

```
imageButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

you don't need to set drawable image when you already set it in you xml

Comment: what is imageButton1?
Is it the name of the image file?

Comment: no it is the id of imagebutton in xml file see your code

Comment: Oh I get it!! 
Thank you very much :) I'm learning something :)

Comment: Anyway, why doesn't this work? 
int buttonId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("button", "drawable", this.getPackageName());

Answer (score 0):

Button is not set correctly in buttonId variable, do  this intead:

```
imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1)
```

and also please post your code here